# Python converting Japanese input into question marks

Tags: python, filenames

I'm trying to write a program that will take file names and rename them by changing the order of the words. It works fine for most files, but I have a few files with Japanese characters in the file name for which the program does not work. I think this is because it converts the characters into question marks (I've checked this using print) and then can't find the file because the file has Japanese characters in it, not question marks. How can I work around this?

Edit:
Yes, I'm using Windows.

A recreation of my code is posted below (I'm fairly new to this, so it may be very inefficient and hard to read).

```
import os

def Filenames(filelist):
    filenames = []
    for name in filelist:
        name = name.split(".") #Take off file extension
        filenames.append(name)
    return filenames

def ReformatName(directory):
    filelist = []
    name = []    

    filelist = os.listdir(directory)
    filenames = Filenames(filelist)

    for doc in filenames: #Docs are in form "Date Name Subject DocName", want to turn into "Subject DocName Date"
        doc1 = doc.split(" ")
        date = doc1[0]
        subject = doc1[2]
        docname = doc1[3]

        newdoc = "%s %s %s.docx" %(subject, docname, date)
        doc = ".".join(doc)
        os.rename(os.path.normpath(directory + os.sep + doc), os.path.normpath(directory + os.sep + newdoc))
```

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: It sounds like your program is not unicode-safe, which is generally bad. Maybe if you post some code we can help you with making it work with non-ASCII input?

Comment: Updated to answer questions.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a quite complicated solution for problems with windows console:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import codecs

def setup_console(sys_enc="utf-8"):
    reload(sys)
    # Calling a system library function if we're using win32
    if sys.platform.startswith("win"):
        import ctypes
        enc = "cp%d" % ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetOEMCP() #TODO: check on win64/python64
    else:
        # It seems like for Linux everything already exists
        enc = (sys.stdout.encoding if sys.stdout.isatty() else
                    sys.stderr.encoding if sys.stderr.isatty() else
                        sys.getfilesystemencoding() or sys_enc)

    # Encoding for sys
    sys.setdefaultencoding(sys_enc)

    # Redefining standard output streams if they aren't redirected
    if sys.stdout.isatty() and sys.stdout.encoding != enc:
        sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter(enc)(sys.stdout, 'replace')

    if sys.stderr.isatty() and sys.stderr.encoding != enc:
        sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter(enc)(sys.stderr, 'replace')
```

Source: http://habrahabr.ru/post/117236/ (available in Russian only)

Comment: Thanks for your response. What do I do with this? Post it at the beginning of my code?

Comment: @user2293073 Yes, you should call the `setup_console` function in the beginning of your program.